# API to automatically import Woocommerce orders to Magento

Tags: orders, api, import, export, wordpress

I'm looking for the best way to automatically import orders from a Woocommerce shop to Magento.

Do you guys have any ideas how to do that ? CSV auto export/import ?

Comment: I guess you could take a look at Cart2Cart. It is a paid third party service that will try its best to migrate data from one platform to another. Their support is quite reactive, but they are also a bit expensive (I guess less expensive than if you have to develop scripts on both platforms).

Comment: Many thanks for you quick response. I'm going to contact them because it looks like a oneshot migration service not an automated api for long term

Comment: As expected, Cart2Cart is only a one time export.

Comment: If you're looking for a continuous import from orders into Magento you should consider importing them via API (REST or SOAP).

Comment: @Axium I suggested Cart2Cart because you seemed to be willing to migrate from WooCommerce to Magento ^^" sorry for that